# Black screen JavaFX Gluon Application

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, javafxports

I know this was asked before but i couldn't get over this problem... I made an app, and it runs perfectly on desktop a in builds the apk smoothly... But when i instal it on my device(Sony Xperia M2 aqua), it just shows a black screen... Any Help will be apreciated...

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.paneladebarro.PanelaDeBarroFx'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

The MainUi.java

```
package com.paneladebarro;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PanelaDeBarroFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            StackPane root = FXMLLoader.load(PanelaDeBarroFx.class.getResource("/MainUI.fxml"));

            Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 563, 900);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());

            stage.getIcons().add(new Image(PanelaDeBarroFx.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I told you already that the plugin version you are using is really outdated. You need to use the Gluon plugin for your IDE, and it will manage to add the current versions. As for the black screen, run `adb logcat -v threadtime` on the command line to find out about possible exceptions.

Comment: I know it is outdated but it is the only one that is workiing on my eclipse... When i add [this](http://download.gluonhq.com/tools/eclipse/release) to "Instal new software" it stucks on "calculating dependencies"... And then cannot perform operation.. At first it was beacuse it was already instaled, so i unnistaled it and tried again with no sucess... @JoséPereda

Comment: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Gluon Tools 2.4.0 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.4.0)
  Missing requirement: Gluon Plugin 2.4.0 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin 2.4.0) requires 'bundle com.gradleware.tooling.model 0.6.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Gluon Tools 2.4.0 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.4.0)
    To: com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin [2.4.0]

Comment: Then you should try to solve the installation issue first, it doesn't make sense working with a very old plugin. There are too many bug fixes and improvements between 1.0.0-b10 and 1.1.0..

Comment: `Eclipse Oxygen` is fresh and new for all mad programmers: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Oxygen/M2

Comment: @GoXR3Plus Thank YOu!!! It worked!!!

Comment: So you changed the IDE and it worked..?What was your previous `Eclipse` Version?

Comment: Now, could you please direct me to sites where you can learn Android with JavaFX? So ... everything, how to integrate ... manuals, documentation ... @JoséPereda Im new on mobile app development and i have a lot off questions...

Comment: Start by having a look at the Gluon Mobile [Documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.1/) and [Samples](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/). Also there are some screencasts [here](http://gluonhq.com/support/media/).

Comment: Thnks... Now, how to generate the apk... I dont see "Android" gradle task in this new version of gluon plugin

Comment: As far as I know there are the tasks androidInstall to directly install during development, androidRelease and -Debug. Your ide should present these tasks in the "others" section, I think. At least on eclipse's buildship I needed so set a tick somewhere in the related Gradle talk view.